# Change all users attribute in a domain in Active Directory recursively

Tags: recursion, vbscript, attributes, active-directory, ldap

I've got a little script (VBS) to change website attribute of all users :

```
    dim objOU, objUser 

    objOU="OU=Users,DC=mysociety,DC=local"  

    Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://" & objOU)  

on error resume next 
For each objUser in objOU  
    If objUser.Class="user" Then  
            Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objUser.distinguishedName) 
        objUser.Put "wWWHomePage", "http://mysite.mysociety.local/Person.aspx?accountname=mysociety\" & objUser.mailNickname
        objUser.setInfo 
        if err.number <> 0 then 
            wscript.echo "Error processing " & objUser.givenName & ":" & err.number & ", " & err.Description 
            err.clear 
        end if 
    End if 
Next
```

So my problem is that if I precise my objOU up to deepest directories it works perfectly. But it is not a recursive script and with this code it doesn't work because of subdirectories.
I am a very beginner with VBS, could you help me to make this script recursive ?

Thank you by advance and excuse me for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be accomplished very efficiently using threads. In one thread, execute a search
wherein the base object is that point in the directory information tree (DIT) below which all
the entries that must be modified are stored. Use `whole subtree` for the search scope and a
filter that narrows the search results to just the entries that require modification. Use the
OID `1.1` for the list of requested attributes (this will cause the directory server to return
only distinguished names). Assuming the directory administrator allows this search - it may be
denied for resource reasons or security reasons or other reasons - as the search results arrive,
use another thread to construct the modifications on the distinguished names that are being
returned in the search thread. For maximum efficiency, use multiple threads to make the
modifications and use the appropriate concurrence mechanisms for your API.

### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)
- [LDAP: Search Best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)